# code coverage for each source file using karma-coverage and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, webpack, karma-coverage

I am trying to setup the code coverage for the unit test for the angular project. However it gave me some error. Refer https://github.com/angular-class/NG6-starter/issues/58

Answer (score 0):

Refer to implementation in : https://github.com/packetloop/angular-webpack/blob/master/karma.conf.js

and also add a file : https://github.com/packetloop/angular-webpack/blob/master/spec.js